# 1st hover event not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery script which is responsible to show a hidden div on mouseover:

```
function mouseOverBoard() {
    function mouseOverBoard() {
        $(".boardControl").hover(function () { 
            $(this).find(".boardControllers").show(); },
            function () { 
                $(this).find(".boardControllers").hide(); }
            );
    }
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="portlet-header textSmall test boardControl" onmouseover="javascript:mouseOverBoard();" style="background: #e9f2f2; min-height: 55px;">
    <div class="boardControllers" style="display: none;">
        <img src="./images/editSmall.png" alt="Edit" title="Bearbeiten" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <img src="./images/deleteSmall.png" alt="Delete" title="Löschen" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <img src="./images/addNewEmployeeSmall.png" alt="New Employee" title="Mitarbeiter hinzufügen" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:details();"><img src="./images/details.png" alt="Details" title="Detailsansicht" /></a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div>
    Downloadbereich aktualisieren

</div>
```

It's working without any problems but only after the event was triggered the first time.
For the first time nothing happens (the hidden div is just not shown).

Comment: You have a function in a other function. It s normal ?

Comment: @DoubleYo - that's what we call the old Inception technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the functions is wrong. Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boardControl").hover(function () { 
      $(this).find(".boardControllers").show(); },
        function () { 
          $(this).find(".boardControllers").hide(); }
    );
});
```